# Just got fired after 4 months what do I do

Tags: job-search, termination

I just got fired after 4 months (I think I was placed poorly but who cares what I think) after being unemployed for 3 months I just graduated a year ago and I'm looking for my 3rd job
If I was an employer I wouldn't touch me what do I do?
They said my last day is 2 weeks from now is there any hope to save myself?
I don't have anyone to turn to

Comment: Hey @Balin sorry to hear that. However, we will need you to be more specific and detailed in order to help you. What is the core question you have? What industry is this job from? Mind including or mentioning your location to give more specific answers based on such fact? Please, while you are at it, take the [tour] and check the [help/dont-ask] to get a better idea on how to properly ask questions around here (you will see that asking "what do I do now" is not something we can help you with, although, as a comment, it's obvious you have to update resume and start applying to jobs ASAP)...

Comment: Sorry still in shock I was doing aws but I am really a developer (python especially) I also have a few certs in cyber security (sec+ and cysa+)

Comment: Whatever you decide to do, you shouldn't feel like you're unemployable. Try to keep a positive mind about things, and start applying for jobs.

Comment: It would help to walk through your employment history.  If you graduated a year ago, you were employed for 4 months, unemployed for 3 months before that, and are looking for your third job, that implies that you had your first job for something like 5 months after graduation.  What happened there?  What caused you to be fired this time (and are you sure you were fired rather than, say, being laid off)?  You can certainly recover from a couple of very short jobs but you'll want to take some time to assess what went wrong before you make the same mistakes again.

Comment: "is there any hope to save myself?" not in that company. Firings are not reversed by employers (unless a forced to by a court order). Stay positive and look into the future by analyzing the past and improving.

Comment: There is still time. you only graduated last year there is still hope. Start handing out your resume to those companies which you want to work with/in. also, write down your 4 months experience of the previous company you got fired it will explain your 4 moths gap from the 1-year gap. Most of the companies still understand 1-year gap is not much of a big deal for freshly graduates.

Comment: "I was an employer I wouldn't touch me" — bullshit. Take a day to pout, then cleanse yourself of this negative thinking. You got hired once. People who got fired get hired all the time. You'll get hired.

Comment: What did they tell you was the reason for firing you?

Answer (score 5):

1. "Is there any hope to save myself?"
   Unlikely. If you are in a very small company, and your team-lead is basically the owner of the company (or the decision-maker), you *may* have a chance to impress them  enough to stay. In all other situations, everyone in power will basically switch to being "deaf".
   The only other chance may be if you somehow become the only one who can maintain the company's software, an important client or project. But that is mostly daydreaming or incredibly good luck.
2. "what do I do"

- Start applying for new jobs right now.
- Use your remaining time to network colleges: Someone might recommend you to another company, or they might have a tip which company would be hiring someone with your skills. They might know people who quit before you did (and maybe started a company or became a valued contributer somewhere else) - and those people usually do not mind if you were fired by your current employer. Ask your colleges if you may add them as contacts in career-networks like xing or linkedin.
- Make sure anybody will remember you as a pleasant person who is easy to work with. Do not burn bridges! A potential new employer might call your current company.

3. "I'm looking for my 3rd job If I was an employer I wouldn't touch me"
   Consider not mentioning your shortest employment. You can avoid lying and still make your resume look good.

[Edit:
Check if your current employer is using some technology that is in high demand on the job-market. You can perhaps use the last two weeks learning more about it. Two weeks experience in tool xyz might not be much, but it is more than hundreds of other applicants may have ;-)

Also: Good luck and do not worry. Many experienced "veterans" did have similar streaks in their life!]